# How can I load a document into couchdb using "use CouchDB::Client;" modules in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I tried using the CPAN `CouchDB` Modules in my Perl script.
But, unable to use the methods in the modules.

```
my $c = CouchDB::Client->new(uri=>'http://databaseurl:5989);

my $db=$newdoc->retrieve('0520027d8c01dw3b');
```

And got the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "retrieve" via package "CouchDB::Client" at test.pl line 22.
```

Retrieve method exists in the `CouchDB::Client::Doc.pm`, yet I see the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the document object instead of db object

```
my $doc = $db->newDoc->retrieve('0520027d8c01dw3b');
```

See related discussion on perlmonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1124395